# Alternatives to SitecorePackageDeployer

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

We're upgrading to Sitecore 10.2, and have previously used [Sitecore Package Deployer](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/SitecorePackageDeployer) in a previous version of Sitecore in our CI/CD process. I noticed this package has not been updated since 2019, and the docs say it's only been tested up to v9.0. Is there a different or better process to handle this in 10.x? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When moving to Sitecore XM/XP 10.1+ you'll want to consider newer options available. In your case, you may find that ItemsAsResources (IAR) is an ideal approach to solving the issue of moving developer-owned items through environments.

The Sitecore CLI includes a [plugin](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/developer-tools/items-as-resources-plugin.html) for generating the IAR files.

I [blogged](https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2023/01/working-with-unicorn-and-sitecore-cli.html) about some of my experience transitioning from a deployment that synced YAML items to using the IAR files. It has its quirks but is a good alternative.